# How to show only waypoints using Google Maps API 3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using this code example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable

And the result is this:
[image]

But i not like show the directions...  I would like to show only waypoints.. like this:
[image]

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: If you don't like the way the Directions Renderer renders the side panel, you need to render it yourself (or modify it after it is created, but that could be fragile).  What does your code look like to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could always hide that unwanted part of the panel using additional css:

```
.adp-directions, .adp-summary {
    display:none;
}
```

Check out this fiddle ( I think you have to run it again after it loads) : https://jsfiddle.net/eyxyhwor/1/

Comment: How do I create a button equal to the created by Google Maps ?

For example, when you click in `<a href="#">Show Cocklebiddy WA Waypoint B</a>` on the map highlight the waypoint B